# FrameTicks fails to maintain coordinate consistency in Graphics3D for ArrayPlot and Arrow

Tags: graphics

A simple illustration:

```
chess = Array[RandomInteger[20] &, {10, 10}];
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {0, 10, 10}, {0, 10, 0}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}];
arrow = Sequence @@ {Red, Thickness[Large], Arrow[{{1, .5, .5}, {1, 9.5, 9.5}}]};
```

> The coordinate setting of `Arrow` is consistent with `ArrayPlot`:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture@ArrayPlot[chess], poly, poly, arrow}]
```

[image: without]

> Once the `FrameTicks` option is set, the frame is rescaling the chessboard and the coordinates for `Arrow` and `ArrayPlot` are no longer consistent:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture@ArrayPlot[chess, FrameTicks -> All], poly, arrow}]
```

[image: with]

I tried a variety of settings e.g. `PlotRangePadding -> 0`, `ImagePadding -> 0` which resolves the scaling but makes the labels disappear.

Looking at `FullForm` it seems the internal `Raster` is unchanged, so this did not give me clue on how to resolve. There is an option `DefaultBoundaryStyle` but I could not find anything on this in the documentation.

**How can I keep the coordinates consistent AND have a labelled frame?**

Comment: apologies, struggling with fixing the pictures.

Comment: `Graphics3D[{Texture@ArrayPlot[chess, FrameTicks -> All], poly, Red, 
  Thickness[Large], 
  Scale[Arrow[{{1, .5, .5}, {1, 9.5, 9.5}}], {1, .9, .9}, {1, 5, 5}]}]`?

Comment: Wow ... problem easier to fix than getting the pictures to show up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @kglr, answering myself for completeness: use `Scale[Arrow[...]]` to ensure re-scaling to remain consistent with the `ArrayPlot` coordinates.

```
Graphics3D[{Texture@ArrayPlot[chess, FrameTicks -> All], poly, Red,Thickness[Large], Scale[Arrow[{{1, .5, .5}, {1, 9.5, 9.5}}], {1, .9, .9}, {1, 5, 5}]}]
```